# Releasing from Trunk or Branch?

Tags: svn, version-control, teamcity, release-management

We've recently (last 2 months) started to use TeamCity tfor our deployments. This has taught us a lot about actually using SC properly, the pitfalls and working in a team with multiple projects. However we are still unclear on how best to use trunk, branches and tags.

Our current process is:

- A unit of work is requested.
- New branch is created for developer.
- Once development is finished in the branch, the trunk is merged back into the branch to ensure any recent changes are included.
- At this point the branch is ready for testing, and this is where our uncertainty starts!

I've heard other developers say that we should only be releasing from the trunk, and I'm sure that when releasing to production this is true. However, at the stage when a branch is ready for testing, it doesn't seem appropriate that we should merge back into the trunk and then release to our test environment, or should we be?

The other approach I have considered is just having a branch called TEST and then always merge and release to test environments from there, but there are perhaps hidden pitfalls with this approach too.

Could I please ask for some guidance/advice on this topic? What do you do for example?

I wont broach the subject of tags in this post, as I understand it's probably complicating the issue.

Thanks in advance
dotdev

Answer (score 4):

I've found that forcing all development on one branch forces the developers to be careful and to take in account all work. I've seen using a branch-per-feature, but I've always found issues with it:

- There's a lot of time with me playing mother hen. *"Have you checked in your changes?"*, *"Did you deliver your changes to trunk"*, *"Have you been keeping your branch up to date with the changes in trunk"*. I rather do actual CM work instead of pestering developers.
- There's always the *last minute* delivery of code into trunk that causes merge issues. You think you're all set for the release, and suddenly an avalanche of work comes pouring into trunk two days before the release date.
- One idea of working on a branch is that it lets you pick and choose what you want to release. You can work on Feature *A*, Feature *B*, and Feature *C*, then decide if you want to release only one of those features, two of them, or all three of them! The problem is that these features are not independent of each other, and you can end up with as many as 50 or more branches all happening at once. The merge is never as smooth as in theory.
- Speaking of merges: Merging is the most rough and awful aspect of development. It is fraught with danger, and most developers are bad at it.

When you have all developers work on a single branch, you stop merging because there's nothing to merge. Developers are never *unaware* of someone's changes because it's in the branch. Developers will keep each other in line. Yes, you lose the ability to pick and choose features, but this is best done before the sprint.

So, I release from trunk? No. I release from a branch. There will come a time when you do most of the development work for the next release. Now, it's just bug fixes, and you only need one or two developers to swat bugs that are found in testing.

This is when you make your release branch. Most of your developers will continue working on *trunk* (or whatever you call it), and the bugs found in the release are fixed on the branch. When you make a release, you tag and release off the branch. If you need to make an *intermediate release* for bug fixes, you can use that same branch.

For example: We work on trunk for our 1.2 release. When we get the work to *feature complete*, I'll make a Release 1.2 branch. Now, all work on Release 1.2 is on the branch and work for my future release (probably 1.3) will continue on trunk. When we complete work on Release 1.2, we tag the branch and release from the branch.

Sooner or later, bugs found in Release 1.2 need to be fixed. Trunk is already 1.3. However, we'll just do the bug fixes on the 1.2 branch and do 1.2.1 from there.

There are times when I need a *feature branch*. For example, I have a feature that will take a while to work on, and be implemented in the future. In this case, I'll create a *feature branch*, and allow the developers to work on that. However, the developers must keep merging the parent branch into that feature branch to keep up with all of the changes. AND, when they have finished work on that feature, we merge the parent branch into the feature branch, test and make sure everything works, then merge the feature branch into the parent, and make sure the parent branch matches the feature branch.

So, to recap:

- We do all of our work on *trunk* together as a team.
- When we get to some magical mystery point (feature complete, or last sprint) we branch to the release branch.
- Work continues on trunk for some *future* release while the release branch is for the next release.
- When the release work is finished, we release and tag from the branch.
- We are not dogmatic. There are times when we will do feature branching. Maybe, if you have a very small development team, you might not branch on release. You simply release off of trunk, and if you need to make a patch, you branch at the release point and make a patch.

The main point is that we try to avoid branching when we don't have to, and keep merging to a minimum. I don't care how great a merging algorithm is, or how automated the merges, merging is a sloppy process and few people know how to do it correctly (or at least take the effort to do it correctly).

Creating a branch is like creating a child: Once you create one, you have to watch it and tend to it and make sure it stays out of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would suggest:

1) Do all development on the Trunk branch and use it for testing. I assume you have multiple features/bugs being worked on simultaneously. I would avoid creating separate branch for each feature unless you constantly merge back changes from trunk to the feature branch.

2) Once you are ready to release create a new RELEASE branch from the Trunk at that point. Deploy the branch to QA/Staging environment to do the test.

3) Developers can start working on the new features and start checking-in changes to Trunk after the RELEASE branch is created. Any regression issues found during testing will be fixed in RELEASE branch first and then merged back to MAIN.

4) Any changes to code in RELEASE branch will then be pushed to QA/Staging for further testing.

5) Once the Release is done any bug found in production will be fixed in RELEASE branch and hot-fixed to Prod and also merged back to Trunk.

I would suggest to create a new branch for every RELEASE and then get rid of old RELEASE branches periodically instead of using labels.

So my suggestion is to always release to production from the RELEASE branch. Since you are using teamcity you should also think about creating a continuous integration build (i.e. building the project everytime there is a check-in)

Comment: Regarding point (5), would you also need to merge directly to RELEASE.v2 branch? You mentioned merging production bugs to trunk, but how does that fix get to RELEASE.v2? Cherry picking the fix from trunk to RELEASE.v2 sounds a little messy.

Comment: What do you mean by RELEASE.v2 branch? There will only be one active release branch at a time. I wouldn't suggest creating a separate RELEASE branch for hotfix if you meant that.

Comment: So RELEASE branch goes to production, you are now ready to UAT the next release, so you create branch RELEASE.v2 and begin to stabilise. So now you have an emergency production bug so you commit fix X in  RELEASE branch (production). Now fix X also needs to go to trunk as this is the procedure (point 5), however RELEASE.v2 is currently in UAT, so fix X needs to somehow get into the RELEASE.v2 branch. I may have missed something when going through your procedure?